# Given $n$ numbers, choose $4$ times with replacement, each time choose the number not less than the former one. How many possibilities?

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n(n>>4)$ numbers $\{1, 2, 3,...,n\}$, choose $4$ times with replacement, resulting in a number sequence($w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4$). Each time choose the number not less than the former one, which means $1\le w_1\le w_2\le w_3\le w_4\le n$.

How many possible combinations of the number sequences?
What if the problem generalizes to choose $k$ times with $k<<n$?

e.g. $n$ = 16, then sequences (1, 2, 3, 4),(3, 6, 11, 15),(16, 16, 16, 16) all fit the constraints, while (16, 2, 6, 10) doesn't.

If I choose 4 times without constraints, the possible combinations will be $n^4$. I'm not sure how to calculate the upper question analytically. But I did a simulation numerically. It seems that the possible combinations related to $\frac{n^4}{4!}$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Please **edit your question** to provide this information.  Questions that don't show any independent effort to reach a solution usually are not well received here.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you are asking.  Any number might come out the maximum of the four choices, so there are $n$  "possibilities".  Presumably you meant to ask about the probability distribution or something like that?

Comment: @lulu I think that the question is: how many non-decreasing sequences of 4 numbers are there, where each number $\in [1,n]$.

Comment: @user2661923  Sure, maybe.  But why introduce the random selection if probabilities are irrelevant?   Your sequences aren't equi-probable, of course.   Anyway, the OP ought to clarify the question.

Comment: @lulu "But why introduce the random selection...".  Good question.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the intended question is: how many non-decreasing sequences of 4 numbers are there, where each number $\in [1,n]$?  If this is not the intended question, then the hint below is inappropriate.  If so, please advise with a trailing comment, or address a comment to me, following your question.

---

You haven't shown any work so all I'm allowed to offer is a *hint*.  The hint applies to $k=4$.

If you knew that the numbers were all distinct, you could take all possible such sequences and divide by $(4!)$, re the symmetry of such sequences.

Taking this approach, you have to precisely count how many 4-number sequences are possible, where exactly 2 of the numbers are the same, exactly 3 of the numbers are the same, and exactly 4 of the numbers are the same.  For each such *type of* sequence, you must choose the appropriate scalar.  The scalar will be clear, by a symmetry argument.

The only trap is that if exactly 2 of the numbers are the same, the other two numbers **might** also be the same.

---

**Edit**
Note that the above approach is routine, for $(k=4)$, but will **not** generalize well for unspecified constant $k$.  I think that for unspecified constant $k$, a more elegant approach is needed, if feasible.

Comment: Could you explain about the symmetry of such sequences?Thx.

Comment: @hxuaj Assume that $(n=4)$.  How many 4 number sequences are there, that use the numbers $\{1,2,3,4\}$, where each number is used once?  Of these sequences, how many of them are in strictly ascending order?  How many such sequences are there where two of the number are the same (e.g. $\{1,1,2,3\}$)?  Of these sequences, how many of them are in non-decreasing order?  If you answer these questions by **manually counting**, you will understand.